# Macro with zero arguments

Tags: c++, macros

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code. When I pass 1 argument to LOG_INFO, it works fine, but fails with 0 arguments.

```
#define LOG_INFO(...) CLOG(INFO, "default", ##__VA_ARGS__)

LOG_INFO() << "Log using default file";
```

When I compile this code I get this error:

```
error:
expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

This is what I did to debug it.

When I run `g++ -E` on this file, `LOG_INFO()` IS expanded correctly:

```
CLOG(INFO, "default") << "Log using default file";
```

When I replace

```
LOG_INFO() << "Log using default file";
```

with

```
CLOG(INFO, "default") << "Log using default file";
```

It compiles fine! But when I put back the pre-expansion macro, it fails again.

To answer commentators: 
Here's the definition of CLOG

```
#define CLOG(LEVEL, ...)\
    C##LEVEL(el::base::Writer, el::base::DispatchAction::NormalLog, __VA_ARGS__)
```

full file can be found here:

https://github.com/easylogging/easyloggingpp/blob/master/src/easylogging%2B%2B.h

running:
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

Comment: What compiler are you using? What options? You should show a complete, minimal example, including the entire .cpp file, and compiler command-line, and compiler output - not snippets.

Comment: I think there is nothing you can do about this. IIRC the GCC compiler "fixed" this but its non-standard. You have a trailing comma with empty args.

Comment: @Galik, I have updated my question, the expansion seems to work fine. This is very weird

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. You describe behavior that seems precisely like what you'd expect and then your question just stops.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ah sorry I wasn't clear in the question, I will rephrase

Comment: @Kam Yeah, you're running GCC so you must have a different problem...

Comment: Macro defined in a open source logging lib called easylogging++ it's a header only library consisting of 1 file

Comment: So that is C++ only? Please add the macro definition.

Comment: "When I run g++ -E on this file, LOG_INFO() IS expanded correctly:" Hmm... why if the `CLOG` macro not expanded then? `-E` woudl expand all macros actually.

Comment: @Olaf Assume it is :) for this example I commented out the header library. But doing the same exercise with the header library leads to same outcome (obviously different and more complicated expansion) and same behaviour. I am no longer next to my computer but will add the expansion later on if you think it's useful.

Comment: @Kam: Not sure if it helps; Macro expansion can be a beast to debug, so it is often just a good idea to see the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run `g++ -E` on this file, `LOG_INFO()` IS expanded correctly:
>
> `CLOG(INFO, "default") << "Log using default file";`

I don't think this is expanded correctly. It should be fully expanded.

```
CLOG(INFO, "default")
```

should not be in the expanded file. It should have expanded to

```
CINFO(el::base::Writer, el::base::DispatchAction::NormalLog, "default")
```

which in turn should have expanded to something else. The actual line will be some crazy C++ which contains no macros.

---

I think you are running into a defect in the `##__VA_ARGS__` engine. Something similar to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56825 or https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61613.

---

You can test this by replacing

```
#define LOG_INFO(...) CLOG(INFO, "default", ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

with

```
#define LOG_INFO() CLOG(INFO, "default")
```

and looking at the output of `g++ -E`.

---

As to a possible solution, you may have luck with some double expansion tricks.

```
#define LOG_INFO_HELPER(...) , ## __VA_ARGS__
#define LOG_INFO_COMMA_AND(...) LOG_INFO_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_INFO(...) CLOG(INFO, "default" LOG_INFO_COMMA_AND(__VA_ARGS__))
```

See https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19141

I'm not 100% sure this will work in your case.